# Determining $z$ given $P(Z>z)$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Need to calculate $P(Z>z) = 0.4$, now my thinking was $0.4 = 1- P(Z <z)$ ($Z$ score table I'm given only has $Z<z$), so I found a value of $0.206$ which gives me an approximate $0.6$ which is $1-0.6 = 0.4$ meaning $P(Z > 0.206)$. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

Because of symmetry of the normal distribution, you could also use $P(Z>z) = P(Z<-z) = 0.4$

The answer I receive is $z = 0.25335$, using -NORM.S.INV(0.4) in excel.

Comment: In R, where `qnorm` is standard normal quantile function (inverse CDF): `-qnorm(.4)` returns 0.2533471. Also, `qnorm(.6)` returns 0.2533471.  // Searching 4-place body of printed normal CDF table for closest to 0.4, I found 0.4013 corresponding to -0.25 in 2-place margin; next closes 0.3974 corresp to -0,26. One could interpolate to get a third decimal place.

Comment: The Reason why I did 1- P(Z<z) is cause the Z-score table my professor has provided is only applicable values for P(Z <z)

Comment: That part is OK, but answ to 3 places is -0.253, not your -0.206, which is suspect is from mis-reading table margin.

Comment: I misread the Z-Score Table it was actually 0.2 and 0.06 meaning 2.6 Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

$P(Z>z)=0.4$ Means $z=0,25$

The table at 0.6 gives you $0,25$, ($0.26$ is also good as the exact valute is intermediate but not $0.206$) and this number is a quantile., a real number $\in \mathbb{R}$, not a probability

Comment: Sorry for the confusion it was actually 0.2 and 0.06 meaning it would give me 0.26